# I have a large table with many colspans and need the column widths to be equal

Tags: html, css, html-table

I cannot get the columns in this data table to be equal width. I'm attaching the HTML file.  The goal is to get the GAW 325, GAW 331, GAW 333, GAW 334, GAW 337, and GAW 338 to be equal widths. The rest of the cells can resize as needed, there are no other requirements for them. All CSS needs to be inline as I don't have access to the stylesheet.

I tried using fixed-width layout, manually setting the table and TD and TR tags to various widths using inline HTML, CSS, pixels, and percentages.

```
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF; " rowspan="2" valign="bottom">
            <p>Property</p>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF; " colspan="11" >
            <p align="center">Material Sets</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p align="center">GAW 325</p>
            </td>
            <td style="" colspan="3">
            <p align="center">GAW 331<sup>a</sup></p>
            </td>
            <td style="" colspan="2">
            <p align="center">GAW 333</p>
            </td>
            <td style="" colspan="2">
            <p align="center">GAW 334<sup>a</sup></p>
            </td>
            <td style="" colspan="2">
            <p align="center">GAW 337<sup>a</sup></p>
            </td>
            <td style="">
            <p align="center">GAW 338</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>IP Rating<sup>b</sup></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="11" >
            <p align="center">IP67 / IP68</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
            <p>ISO Rating</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <p align="center">–</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <p align="center">30 m water<br />
            @ 10 min</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="7" >
            <p align="center">–</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>Insertion loss @ 1kHz<sup>c</sup></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">&lt; 2.5 dB</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">&lt; 4 dB</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">&lt; 1.5 dB</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">&lt; 1.8 dB</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">&lt; 1.3 dB</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>Adhesive type</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="11" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">Acrylic</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>Adhesive temperature resistance</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">-40 °C to 100 °C</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">-40 °C to 85 °C</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">-20 °C to 85 °C</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>Membrane type</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="11" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">ePTFE</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>Membrane characteristic</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">Oleophobic</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">Hydrophobic</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">Oleophobic</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">Hydrophobic</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">Oleophobic</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF; width:16%" >
            <p>Membrane color</p>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
            <p align="center">Black</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
            <p align="center">Black</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
            <p align="center">White</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
            <p align="center">Black</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
            <p align="center">White</p>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
            <p align="center">Black</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>Support material</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="6" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">PET-Nonwoven / PET</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="5" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <p align="center">PET</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
            <p>RoHS <sup>d</sup></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="11" >
            <p align="center">Meets threshold requirements</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The goal is to get the GAW 325, GAW 331, GAW 333, GAW 334, GAW 337, and GAW 338 to be equal widths.

Comment: you can try set a min width or width  to the content `table p {min-width:15vw}` here is the idea https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmBoMN

Comment: Must you use a table for that row? I mean, can it be something like `<tr><td colspan="11"><div><span>GAW334</span>...</div></td></tr>`? If so, I guess I recommend using flexbox (`display: flex`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to `<table style="...">`:

```
table-layout:fixed; width:100vw
```

To each `<td style="...">GAW*</td>` add:

```
width: 14vw;
```

and `colspan="2"`

**Add an extra `colspan` to each row.**

**Optional:** Changed key `<td>` into `<th>`.

A `<table>` with [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) style allows us to assign a width to each column. This is done be assigning width to the top most applicable `<td>/<th>`, if it's not exactly the top most cell the `<td>/<th>` with the largest width in the column will determine column width.

**Some Advice:** 
<sup>I'm aware that OP cannot use CSS -- this is for future readers</sup>

- Use classes to declare style not inline-styles.

  > `<th class='header'></th>`
  >
  > `<td style='color:#FFFFFF;'></td>`
- Deprecated attributes: `align`, `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`, `border`, `valign`, and `bgcolor` should not be used -- there are CSS equivalents available.

  ```html
  <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='table-layout:fixed;width:100vw'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="width:14vw;color:#FFFFFF; " rowspan="2" valign="bottom">
          <p>Property</p>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF; " colspan="12">
          <p align="center">Material Sets</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style='width:14vw' colspan="2">
          <p align="center">GAW<br>325</p>
        </th>
        <th style="width:14vw" colspan="2">
          <p align="center">GAW<br>331<sup>a</sup></p>
        </th>
        <th style="width:14ww" colspan="2">
          <p align="center">GAW<br>333</p>
        </th>
        <th style="width:14vw" colspan="2">
          <p align="center">GAW<br>334<sup>a</sup></p>
        </th>
        <th style="width:14vw" colspan="2">
          <p align="center">GAW<br>337<sup>a</sup></p>
        </th>
        <th style="width:14vw" colspan="2">
          <p align="center">GAW<br>338</p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p>IP Rating<sup>b</sup></p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="12">
          <p align="center">IP67 / IP68</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p>ISO Rating</p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p align="center">–</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p align="center">30 m water<br /> @ 10 min</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="8">
          <p align="center">–</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p>Insertion Loss @ 1kHz<sup>c</sup></p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">&lt; 2.5 dB</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">&lt; 4 dB</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">&lt; 1.5 dB</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">&lt; 1.8 dB</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">&lt; 1.3 dB</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p>Adhesive Type</p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="12" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">Acrylic</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p><small>Adhesive Temp Resistance</small></p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">-40 °C to 100 °C</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">-40 °C to 85 °C</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">-20 °C to 85 °C</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p><small>Membrane Type</small></p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="12" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">ePTFE</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p><small>Membrane Characteristic</small></p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center"><small>Oleophobic</small></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center"><small>Hydrophobic</small></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center"><small>Oleophobic</small></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center"><small>Hydrophobic</small></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center"><small>Oleophobic</small></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF; width:16%">
          <p><small>Membrane Color</small></p>
        </th>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
          <p align="center"><small>Black</small></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
          <p align="center">Black</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
          <p align="center">White</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
          <p align="center">Black</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
          <p align="center">White</p>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; width:16%">
          <p align="center"><small>Black</small></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p>Support Material</p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="6" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">PET-Nonwoven / PET</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="6" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <p align="center">PET</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#5e86a0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
          <p>RoHS <sup>d</sup></p>
        </th>
        <td colspan="12">
          <p align="center">Meets Threshold Requirements</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat hacky approach using padding in the cells. It ends up wrapping the text, but you can play around with it and hopefully get a decent result.

```
        <tr>
        <td>
        <p align="center"  style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">GAW 325</p>
        </td>
        <td style="" colspan="3">
        <p align="center"  style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">GAW 331<sup>a</sup></p>
        </td>
        <td style="" colspan="2">
        <p align="center"  style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">GAW 333</p>
        </td>
        <td style="" colspan="2">
        <p align="center"  style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">GAW 334<sup>a</sup></p>
        </td>
        <td style="" colspan="2">
        <p align="center"  style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">GAW 337<sup>a</sup></p>
        </td>
        <td style="">
        <p align="center"  style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">GAW 338</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

html tables are always hard to get exactly right it seems. I see what you mean; trying to edit the cell widths directly cause abnormal results.

here is a fiddle with my edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/exv05h7u/4/

Again, not the smoothest or most elegant approach, but hopefully it helps :)